# connect the MongoDB shell to an external database

Tags: mongodb

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQDtr.png)
I am trying to connect to external database from mongo shell. How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start the mongo shell program with the `--host` argument, otherwise it will connect to localhost by default (as seen in line #3 of your console output). I believe for MLab you'll also need to supply your credentials to avoid an authentication error.

Try this:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\server\3.4\bin\mongo.exe --host  ds131492.mlab.com/locations -u username -p password
```